# Misconception of gas laws

Tags: gas-laws, temperature, pressure

I face a misconception with gas laws: Boyle’s law, Charles’ law, and Gay-Lussac’s law.
This is because each law of these assumes the constancy of one of the three following variables (the pressure, the volume, the absolute temperature) and then studies the relation between the other two.
Isn’t this a contradiction?
I mean for instance: Charles’ law states: "the volume of an ideal gas at constant pressure is directly proportional to the absolute temperature.” 
But how the pressure is constant, didn’t Boyle just say that pressure is inversely proportional to volume?

Comment: Suppose the overall law is PV-nRT.  Mathematically, doesn't this mean that, at constant pressure, the volume is proportional to temperature?  And doesn't it also require that, at constant temperature, pressure is inversely proportional to volume?

Comment: @ Chet Miller. The ideal gas law should be clearly written, without a minus sign. It should be : PV = nRT. And it should be mentioned that P is the pressure, V the gas volume, n the amount of gas in moles, R is a constant (8.314 J K-1 mol-1), and T is the absolute temperature in Kelvin

Comment: See also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/127772/79678 for a bit more detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/58330/79678.

Comment: Sorry @Maurice I accidentally typed a minus sign instead of an equal sign, and my vision is not what it used to be (so I didn't notice that I had done that).  Please excuse an old man.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we combine all the three gas laws into a single ideal gas equation?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58330/how-can-we-combine-all-the-three-gas-laws-into-a-single-ideal-gas-equation)

Answer (score 2):

There is no contradiction. Each law is valid under a *certain* conditions.

> This is because each law of these assumes the constancy of one of the three following variables (the pressure , the volume , the absolute temperature) and then studies the relation between the other two. Isn’t this a contradiction?

This is how scientist design experiments. Suppose a teacher wants to assess your chemistry knowledge in an examination room in writing. There are so many variables that would affect your performance. For example, difficulty level of questions, room temperature, humidity, room light, chair comfort and noise level.

What if the teacher, the starts changing all these variables simultaneously in the exam room while you are writing the exam? Certainly, anyone would become crazy under those conditions and it would be hard to assess your true exam results.

Would anyone be able to assess the outcome? So it is better to keep all the variables constant and then vary the difficulty level of questions.

Now let us say, we wish to see the affect of room temperature on your exam performance. What would you like to do? Keep the remaining variables constant, just change the room temperature.

So experimentally, it is easy to alter one variable at a time.

Boyle law studies the pressure behaviour of a gas with constant temperature.
Charles law studies the volume behaviour of a gas with constant pressure.

Do you still see a contradiction?

Comment: I am trying to imagine what it'd be like to take an exam under those conditions. You might try a subway train!

Comment: @BuckThorn, Not a bad idea ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Boyle, Gay-Lussac, Charles laws can all be deduced from the more general ideal gas law, namely : $\ce{PV = nRT}$, provided you know that P is the pressure of the gas, V is the volume of the container, *n* is the amount of gas, in moles, R is a constant ( $\ce{R = 8.314 J K^{-1} mol^{-1}}$), and T is the absolute temperature in Kelvin.

Let's show that Boyle's law is a particular case of PV = *n*RT. In Boyle's experiments, P and V may change, but *n* and T are constant. So the product of the three constants *n*RT is also constant: it is a new constant, in all experiments by Boyle. And Boyle's law is PV = constant = *n*RT. Or : $\ce{P_1V_1 = P_2 V_2}$

Let's show that Charles's law is also a particular case of PV = *n*RT. Charles's law states that a given volume V of gas is proportional to the temperature T, at constant pressure P. It has nothing to do with Boyle's law, which was valid at a given constant temperature. As the pressure P (and the amount of gas *n*) is a constant in all Charles' experiments, the constants *n*, R and P can be grouped into a new constant *n*R/P = k,  and the volume V changes with T. The initial law can be rewritten : V = (*n*R/P)·T = k·T. The volume V is proportional to the temperature T.

Similarly, Gay-Lussac's law is also a particular case of PV = *n*RT. Gay-Lussac's law states that the pressure P of a given amount of gas is proportional to the temperature T if the volume V does not change during the experiment. As the volume V (and the amount of gas *n*) is constant, the three constants *n*, R and V, are such that their product *n*R/V is a constant in all Gay-Lussac experiments: These constants *n*, R and V can be regrouped into a new constant *n*R/V = k', and the law can be rewritten : P  = (nR/V)·T = k'·T

This shows that the three gas laws, by Boyle, Gay-Lussac and Charles, are all particular cases of the more general law PV = *n*RT.